# Get the file struct from a pathname

Tags: c, struct, filesystems

I'm modifying a linux filesystem and I would like to know if there a way to get a `struct file *` from an absolute pathname? Specifically the struct defined in [linux/fs.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L765).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a little late, but for anyone looking for an answer to this I used the `open` function on the pathname.